# Get 3 parameters out of a Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string Action>>

Tags: c#, string, dictionary

I have the following code I need the 3 parameters using a foreach:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Action>>
```

I have tried using a `DictionaryEntry` and a `KeyValuePair` but they keep on returning 2 values instead of 3.

Edit:
I'm trying to use a Tuple and I am trying to implement it into my code, but I cant access the tuple inside of the List(element).
Code:

```
                    foreach (List<Tuple<string, string, Action>> element in Classes)
                    {
                        if (ActualText.StartsWith(element.Item1))
                        {
                            string temp1 = ActualText.TrimStart(element.Item1.ToArray());
                            if (temp1 == element.Item2)
                                element.Item3();
                            else
                                print("Unknown extension " + temp1);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: What are the 3 values you are trying to get? Be more specific.

Comment: It's a kind of hard answer your question, You should describe more about your context. Maybee the problem can be solved otherwise. The example you showed is a nested dictionary. So each string dictionary contains a new string dictionary with Actions. You need to step into the first dictionary to get the second, (like a tree)

Comment: Im not sure i understand your question but i think you need 2 foreach nested one for every dictionary inside the dictionary and one for every key,value pair. using a single foreach will always return 2 a keyValuePair which contain the key of the main dictionary and the dictionary associated it will not iterate inside the second dictionary

Answer (score 3):

I agree, you should try using a Tuple here. Try this code:

```
 var foo = new Tuple<string, int, int>("bar", 1, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Action>> dict;

foreach (var kvp1 in dict)
{
    foreach (var kvp2 in kvp1.Value)
    {
        string key1 = kvp1.Key;
        string key2 = kvp2.Key;
        Action a = kvp2.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: kpv1 does not contain .Value

Comment: @DanielJones: It most certainly does! It's a `KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, Action>>`. The `Value` of `kvp1` is the inner dictionary. You'll find that the code I entered there does compile if you assign a value to `dict`. Or are you saying that `Value` is `null`? If that's the case, it's because you didn't put anything there. But since I don't see your code that's populating the dictionary, it's kind of difficult for me to guess what the problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking for is a Tuple...? your question is very vague but here is how you use a tuple.

```
 var foo = new Tuple<string, int, int, int, int, int, int>(
                       "Bar", 7891957, 7781984, 
                       7894862, 7071639, 7322564, 8008278);
```

I hope this helps but in case it isn't what you need. You may want to consider revising your question.

Comment: Does Tuple's have a limit to how many parameters it can hold? eg you have 7.

Comment: The limit is 8. the 8th element must be another Tuple...so essentially it can go on for a while. However, I would advise against that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should explore using a Tuple?
Why would you have a dictionary in a dictionary, assuming you're only having on element in the inner dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

I think that (maybe) what you're looking for is this

assuming mainDictionary is your

```
Dictionary<string1, Dictionary<string2, Action>>
```

we have

```
foreach(var dictionary in mainDictionary){
    foreach(var item in dictionary.Value){
        //dictionary.Key = string1
        //item.Key = string2
        //item.Value = Action
    }
}
```

Comment: Dictionary does not contain anything :(

Comment: @DanielJones Can you post an example code of what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

You can create dictionary with multiple values like this

```
Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>> Multiple_Value_List = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
```

and can add values

```
Multiple_Value_List .Add("Name1", new KeyValuePair<string, string>("category1", "description1"));
```

Multiple_Value_List .Add("Name2", new KeyValuePair("category2", "description2"));
Multiple_Value_List .Add("Name3", new KeyValuePair("category3", "description3"));

Answer (score 0):

Use a Tuple. Here is is the reason WHY.

1. You really want a LIST of **grouped** items.  This grouping is key to your need, and therefore a TUPLE provides that.
2. A Dictionary can perform what you are looking for but it would be a bit complicated as you would have to nest your data-structures.

The goal here is to use the right data-structure for the job, or you will add more complexity to your code, which makes it more difficult to debug, and for others to read and understand it (or your future self).